# Set iframe to full height between fixed footer and header

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, cordova, iframe, phonegap-build

I'm creating a site / html5 app via JQM.

Each page has a fixed header and footer with the central content being scrollable. On one page I have an iframe that is dynamically populated based on a URL -for an external site- passed via local storage.

At present the iframe seems to have some arbitrary height that is much less than the fixed difference between the fixed header and footer.

I need the iframe to fill the gap between header and footer so that the middle section (main) is populated with just the iframe. I need this to be a perfect fit so that I don't get scrolling within scrolling when the externally linked page is larger that the height between the header and footer (eg when viewed on a mobile device).

My HTML looks like this:

```
<body>   
    <div data-role="page" id="step3" class="mainpage" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
            <a href="#left-panel" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-prefetch data-dom-cache="true" data-tap-toggle="false">Menu</a>
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <a data-icon="back" data-rel="back" title="Go back">Back</a>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div role="main" class="ui-content step3" width="100%" height="100%" > 
            <div id="iframe" width="100%" height="100%" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;height:100%"></div>
        </div><!-- /content -->
        <div id="footing" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
            <div id="ad">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>

        <script>
            document.getElementById("iframe").innerHTML="<iframe src='" + localStorage.ExternalListing + "' width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" style=\"padding:0px\;margin:0px\;min-height:500px\;height:100%\;\"></iframe>";
        </script>
        <style>
            .ui-content.step3 {
            padding: 0;
            height:100%;
        }</style>
    </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
```

As you will see I've tried adding 'height:100%' to the relevant sections, and Ive added a min-height (purely for testing purposes) to the iframe. Unfortunately I can't used a fixed height for this since there are so many variations of screen size and resolution for mobile devices.

How can I get the iframe to fill 100% the gap between header and footer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a combination of Omar's & Vikram's solutions since neither work entirely to my needs.

First I've used Vikram's JS to detect the height:

```
function loadIFrame(){
                $(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {
                    var page3 = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
                    if(page3[0].id == "step3")
                    {
                        $.mobile.loading('show');//show ajax loder image
                    }
                });
                //set iFrame height and width to available window
                document.getElementById("iframe").innerHTML = "<iframe src='" + localStorage.ExternalListing + "' width='" + (window.innerWidth) + "' height='" + (window.innerHeight - document.getElementById("header").offsetHeight - document.getElementById("footing").offsetHeight) + "' style='padding:0px;margin:0px;border:0px;'></iframe>";
                //hide ajax loder image
                //setTimeout(function() { $.mobile.loading('hide'); }, 300);
                
                $('iframe').load(function() {
                    $.mobile.loading('hide');
                });
            }
```

And then I've used the following, as suggested by Omar, to recalculate the iframe dimensions on change of orientation.

```
            $(document).on("pagecontainertransition", loadIFrame);
            $(window).on("throttledresize orientationchange", loadIFrame);
```

Comment: Please take some time to rethink You workflow, `$(document).on("pagecontainershow` won't be triggered on `throttledresize orientationchange`, as the page has been already shown...

Comment: That's why the iframe is resized when an orientationchange takes place. Also, it's considered bad practice to dig up a near 5yr old thread.

Answer (score 2):

> Use the below in specific pages only, otherwise it will prevent body/page from scrolling.

The below CSS uses height *inheritance* as well as `box-sizing` to set height of `.ui-content` based on viewport's height. It is responsive to any screen resolution.

Note that page div with fixed toolbars add `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` to accommodate toolbars. The content div inherits height of page minus the padding (88px).

For floating toolbars (non-fixed) the solution is different. If you're interested, I'll post it.

```
html, body,
.mainpage {
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.mainpage,
.mainpage * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mainpage .ui-content {
  padding: 0; /* remove default padding */
  height: inherit; /* full height of viewport - padding of page due to fixed toolbars */
}

.mainpage .ui-content #iframe,
.mainpage .ui-content #iframe iframe {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/zugolo/)**

Comment: @PhillHealey greetings mate! The iframe should look like the small window (result) without the top bar http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/fssr019x/ In that fiddle, I used the same concept of height inheritance to fill screen. Try resizng the box and see how its responsive.

Comment: @PhillHealey I've updated `height` to `100%` as well as demo.

Comment: Ive no idea why, but that just doesn't work for me @Omar

Comment: @PhillHealey are you sure you didn't miss any selector in CSS?

Comment: "I think it's because I insert the iframe into a div via JS, rather than having the iframe physically on the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65368/discussion-between-omar-and-phill-healey).

Answer (score 2):

[**Here's an updated version of your demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/mx20wtzq/)

Merely setting width and height of container divs and the iframe to '100%' will not work.
You'll need to specifically calculate the height and width and apply it to your iframe.

```
document.getElementById("iframe").innerHTML = "<iframe src='" + localStorage.ExternalListing + "' 
    width='" + (window.innerWidth - 20) + "' 
    height='" + (window.innerHeight - document.getElementById("header").offsetHeight - document.getElementById("footing").offsetHeight - 20) + "' 
    style='padding:0px;margin:0px'></iframe>";
```

Check out how the height of the iframe is calculated.

*Note: The 20px offset is ensure scrollbars are not triggered.*

Comment: This seems to prevent the page -with this code- from loading. The ajax spinner just keeps on spinning whenever i click a link that should pass me through to this page.

Comment: Strange! What does the developer console say? Also is the error happening in my demo link or on your page?

Comment: Once the fiddle loads, try and run it again.

Comment: Just spotted it. It was because it was looking for an elementId of 'header' and there wasn't one. Ive added that to my header and now it works. Its doing the job on Firefox on a desktop. Ill five it a quick run in a phonegap wrapper on a mobile and see how that goes.

Comment: Oh yes! My Bad! Forgot to mention that I added that id to access that element through JavaScript.